# dishwasher not spraying hot water DW60

Tags: dishwasher

I've bought a house that came with an integrated new world DW60 dishwasher 
the house had been empty for a number of months.

It worked fine for at least 1 load but now it doesnt enter the wash cycle.
On any program it will drain and fill with cold water but now it no longer sprays hot water after several minutes it drains again and fills with cold water.

What i've tried so far

i've opened it up and checked the main wash pump the drain pump and the heating element. they all got what i thought was normal readings from the multimeter

Main wash pump 75 ohms
drain pump 135 ohms
heating element 30 ohms

the washer was draining fine so wasnt concerned about it but i did find some loose glass around the inlet for that pump.

thinking maybe that was it, i put everything back and switched it on. no joy unfortunately.

if the flowthrough heater was the problem then the machine would spray cold water around but never get up to temperature surely so thats not the problem.

this led me to thinking it is a problem with the main wash pump.
which got normal readings from the multimeter 75ohms. the capacitor had no obvious signs of being blown, and when tested with the multimeter seemed to charge up correctly.
the shaft rotated freely so there was no blockage.

i removed the motor/pump and hooked it up to AC power using an old lamp cord. and it worked ok.
baffled i put the whole thing back together and switched it on still no luck.

and now i'm here.
any ideas?

Comment: I usually connect dishwashers to the hot water line if no hot has been used on the tap that supply's the dishwasher the heater is supposed to heat it up with newer models at least, try running the hot water at the sink close to the washer and see if there is now hot water. Depending on the model you may need to do this before running a cycle.  30 ohms sounds close for a standard element. It could be a bad relay that energizes the element but I haven't seen that in dishwashers not that it could not happen.

Comment: if it was a problem with the heating element then the machine would spray cold water around. i think its a problem with the relay that switches the main pump. do these fail often?

Comment: I was thinking you said not hot just cold spray. The controllers do fail if it is a timer type Knob that turns I have had almost no problems with these but the newer type that run off a small control board with relay out puts have more problems the small relays usually fail on the element and pump. Most of the ones I have repaired have a small Omron relay that the is the problem. This is a bit more advanced than some DIY but can be done a soldering iron will be needed and you have a meter so you can trace the wiring back to the board and identify the relay in question.